# Write cache and write sequence order

Tags: io, filesystems, disk

Let's say we have some binary file (.log), and sequence of write operations, for example log1, log2, log3 and each has some block size n (raw data).

question: can I be sure that log1,log2 and log3 sequences can be written in the correct order in ONE file, even if i have few cache levels (disk hardware and OS level)?

**update**
very interested in what will be with records order (not with records) if we have software or hardware failure (reboot or another reason).

**update**
there can be some percent of write failures, but main question is: will write order stay correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the file system.  If you are doing something with a transactional file system (e.g. [Transactional NTFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transactional_NTFS)) then you get certain guarantees.  If you aren't using a transactional file system, then you get far less guarantees about what happens in hardware failure situations.

Comment: thanks, i get it, but in my question i'm asking more about order of writes,i can accept a certain percentage of write failures, but i need to be sure that order of these writes will not be mixed up.